# Rebuild a drive in a raid 1 array that got disconected

Tags: ubuntu, raid, ubuntu-20.04

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.  I have 2 drives in a RAID 1 array.  One of them got acidentely disconnected but is now connected again.

raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]

I have [U_]

How do I synchronize?

Maybe
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 -a /dev/sda1

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```